# How to customizing API address (Azure API MANAGEMENT)

Tags: api, azure, azure-api-management

I have an api for my customers and I would like to customize the endpoint. Today my customers call the address:
https://XXXX.azure-api.net/YYYY/v1/resource

But I would like that my customers call the following address:
https://XXXX.com/YYYY/v1/resource.

Is it possible? How can i setup this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have API Management at hand, but I would suppose you can bind a custom domain to api management. At the very worst you can front your API Management with an Application Gateway, that is 100% possible and supports custom domains.

Reference:
[Custom domain for Azure application gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752482/custom-domain-for-azure-application-gateway)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set a "Custom domain and SSL" in the API management portal.

You can specify 4 different mappings for a custom domain:

- Proxy/Gateway (for applications calling)
- Portal (for external developers)
- Management (for management)
- SCM (for direct integration/source control/kudu)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! The "Proxy" is called "Gateway" in Azure Portal which made my script failing..... AZ module in Powershell using "New-AzApiManagementCustomHostnameConfiguration" doesn't accept "Gateway" as a HostNameType but it accepts "Proxy"!