# If I have an external public HTTP web server, can I use Microsoft Azure to set up an HTTPS front?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Given I have a HTTP (non-secure) web server up and running with the public address 111.111.111.11:80.

Are there any / what Microsoft Azure products, where I can setup my own custom domain (mydomain.com) as a HTTPS front/reverse proxy to my web server without buying my own certificate?

(Currently, I am using Cloudflare Crypto to achieve this, so I am investigating if Microsoft Azure can achieve this as well in an easy way)

Comment: just for testing https://go-www.com/ it is a static web server but could be used for testing letsencrypt and your custom domain

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the recommended Azure way to do this would be to use [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-introduction) and a CNAME for the custom domain. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752482/custom-domain-for-azure-application-gateway) also has some information on using a custom domain for Application Gateway.

However, if you want to use a custom domain, you will need to buy a certificate. You can do this [through Azure as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site). You can then [use the certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-ssl-portal) for the Application Gateway.

Edit: Sorry, Application Gateway does not seem to support the static public IP in your scenario. You would need to work around that. It might be easier to go a different route then...

Comment: Maybe a load balancer situation works? if you know? I will read about it