# Adding custom domain to App gateway in load balancer

Tags: azure, dns, cname, azure-application-gateway, azure-public-ip

I need your help in understanding how we can create custom domain for app gateway in azure.
I read this post [Custom domain for Azure application gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752482/custom-domain-for-azure-application-gateway), but I am not clear and have some follow up queries.

Sorry, I couldn't ask in the comment of that post since I don't have 50 reputations yet.

So my queries are

- The solution said that we should not use public IP since it is changed on restart of app gateway, but the public ip and app gateway are 2 different resources, so how does restarting app gateway changes the value of public ip resource?
- Let's say, it do changes the address value of public ip resource on restarting the app gateway but doesn't that also changes the DNS (somename.cloudapp.net) which is attached to the public IP?
  If DNS is not changed then does that mean DNS (somename.cloudapp.net) is dynamically mapped to public IP?

As of now, I am simply using the A type record while creating custom domain.
I am trying to understand in what scenarios cname type record will help and how will it help?

Answer (score 0):

Created public IP and Application Gateway in different resources like below:

Application gateway:

[image]

***Note***: If you are using **Application gateway V1** The public IP address and the app gateway are two different resources However, the public IP address is associated with the app gateway, and when the app gateway is restarted, the public IP address is also restarted, which can cause the public IP address to change. The DNS name `somename.cloudapp.net` is dynamically mapped to the public IP address, so if the public IP address changes, the DNS name will also change. As per [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/v1-retirement) App gateway v1 s retiring soon.

Public Ip:

[image]

The Application Gateway v2 SKU supports static public IP addresses and static internal IPs like below:

[image]

[image]

If you stop and start the application gateway, the VIP may change. The DNS name associated with the application gateway doesn't change over the gateway.

Using CNAME alias and direct it to the application gateway's DNS address. The IP address and DNS name won't change in application gateway v2.

***Reference***:

[Frequently asked questions about Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#does-the-ip-or-dns-name-change-over-the-lifetime-of-the-application-gateway)